# 1.9 GB iso file is shown empty

Tags: networking, archive

I recently downloaded a windows game which is 1.9 GB iso file. I mounted it to install with wine and I know it works with wine but no files are shown at all!!! EMPTY! Extracted it but still EMPTY!!! It got me 4 Hours to download.(download speed about 230 kb/s.)
Really I am confused what it is and how it happened. How can a file which has nothing be shown 1.9 GB over internet and on my computer as well. Is the file corrupt? Will I have to redownload it? Or can it be fixed with some software?
Please help!

Comment: I would suggest you to use programs like 7-zip and double click the iso and open with 7-zip. it will show you exact contents of your iso.

Comment: @hardik: 7-zip is a Windows application. We're on an Ubuntu/Linux-centred site.

Comment: @rehan-ullah: Please try to open the `.iso` file in *File Roller*, Ubuntu's default archive manager. What does it show (i. e. make a screen shot)? Are there any error messages? Which ISO file are you referring to? Maybe somebody else can try to reproduce your problem with it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster it's also available in ubuntu here is link to debian package http://packages.debian.org/sid/p7zip-full

Comment: @hardik: `p7zip` is not 7-Zip! The former is a command line program, the latter a graphical archive manager.

Comment: @David Foerster I have tried file roller, and have mounted it accurately. I also have extracted it and the folder is shown empty! No File Inside! but size is 1.9 GB of the iso. The extracted folder zero bytes. No errors are shown. And the file is a Cricket Game.

Comment: Are you using Nautilus to examine the folder? Have you tried CTRL-H to view hidden files?

Comment: @Elder Geek Yeah I have used sudo nautilus and also CTRL-H, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you mounted the image correctly:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 <path_to_image> <path_to_image_mount_point>
```

In any case, the fact that it's `1.9 GB` in size doesn't mean that it contains `1.9 GB` of files, in fact it's totally possible that the image it's actually completely empty.

Comment: Yeah It's fine. But how it happens an 1.9 GB file to be empty. I am wondering!!

Comment: @RehanUllah No idea, i any case it might be just corrupted or in a different format. If you have an `md5` or `sha1` hash to check against it you can run `md5sum <path_to_image>` or `sha1sum <path_to_image>`

Comment: I have one question more. You may help me. I asked just now. I know publishing it in comments is illegal but what can I do. I am really tired of it. Please help! The link of the question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/599490/get-the-download-link-of-file-downloaded-in-software-center