# Get the download link of file downloaded in Software Center

Tags: software-center

I am really asking a question which is many times tagged as [DUPLICATE] but I found no answer. I am downloading FLIGHTGEAR Game which is 1.0 GB with software Center. Unfortunately the power cuts off and download stops and the download speed there is also low. I restart download each time. It gets downloaded 700 MB then power cuts off and when i restart computer and starts download again, it initiates from 0 KB and this process goes on. Please show me the way to get its download link to be used in a download manager and get rid of the problem. Any type of help will be appreciated. Before marking it Duplicate please give a suitable link to get the answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software Center should normally resume previous downloads automatically as should `apt-get`.

Alternatively you can tell `apt-get` to only show URIs of packages to download:

```
apt-get install --print-uris PACKAGE_NAMES...
```

shows the URIs and MD5 check sums of the named packages and all their missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks guy! but this brings the terminal and says to download rather than showing the URIs this does show the packages but will i have to download each one number by number and how will i find the URIs of the packages?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but I get [this output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10644536/) from `LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get install -y --print-uris kde-workspace`, which looks exactly like what you're asking for according to my understanding. If you want something different, please clarify your question.

Comment: Oh! Yeah. This really works for softwares I tried. Thank You. The output file you have given is same as mine. I don't know what mistake I was doing before. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of options available for downloading and installing this software.

Flightgear can be installed with the `apt-get install` command which may provide better results than the software center. To do this press <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal session and enter the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install flightgear
```

Alternatively you can download the Debian package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/flightgear) and install it with the commands below making sure to change the version number and architecture suitable for your system:

```
cd /path/to/download/directory
sudo dpkg -i flightgear_3.0.0-1_amd64.deb
```

You can also download flightgear from sourceforge and compile it by source. This is by far the most complex method of installing flightgear but if you still want to try it, download the source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flightgear/) and enter the commands below:

```
cd /path/to/download/directory
tar -vxjf flightgear-3.4.0.tar.bz2
cd flightgear-3.4.0
mkdir fgbuild
cd fgbuild
cmake ../flightgear -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
sudo make install
```

Lastly, you can check the [flightgear](http://www.flightgear.org/download/main-program/) website for alternative download and installation methods.

Comment: Thank you very much. the sudo apt-get install flightgear resumes the download from where it stopped and I have also downloaded the debian. Thank you guy. Ubuntu Users have always been helping than windows users with out the greed of anything and just want to help in trouble ones. This is the real taste of Ubuntu. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `apt-fast` to speed up downloads (if you have a high-bandwidth connection) and to resume interrupted downloads. I have `apt-fast` available for all supported versions of Ubuntu in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/myppa).

To use it to install Flightgear, you can just run `sudo apt-fast install flightgear`. The syntax is the same as for `apt-get`/`aptitude` (whichever you use).