# From where does Ubuntu install programs when we run sudo apt-get command?

Tags: software-installation

When we run the command in the terminal for downloading and installing a program on Ubuntu in the terminal window from which location does Ubuntu download the program?

For example I want to install Ithor on my computer I should run command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lthor
```

I would like to know from where this package is downloaded and then installed.

And if possible can someone provide me the direct download link for Ithor as my internet connection is very slow and can't download it directly so need an offline installer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does apt-get install do under the hood?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540937/what-does-apt-get-install-do-under-the-hood)

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: And possibly http://askubuntu.com/q/599490/158442, depending on how you want to do it.

Comment: You can download the file from another computer running using `apt-get download Ithor` and install it in your computer using dpkg

Comment: Hello Mohit thanks for the prompt reply , it would be very kind if you can elaborate the dpkg thing , also i would like to download the Ithro package which i used for falshing mobile devices is there a direct download link for it if i am running windows

Comment: You can search and download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com/.To install using dpkg open a terminal there the files are located and then do `sudo dpkg -i file-name.deb`/ `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` is there are multiple packages

Answer (score 3):

It'll get the latest version of `lthor` available as defined by its package lists, as of the last time they were updated (eg `apt-get update`, amongst other commands).

You can see how the decision would go down with apt-cache policy. I don't have `lthor` in my repos so can't show you a specific example but here's another package that I don't have installed currently:

```
$ apt-cache policy xubuntu-desktop
xubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.202
  Version table:
     2.202 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

The `Candidate` version there is what would be installed. `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` is the repo it would be fetched from and verified against. Version `2.202` is the version it would fetch.

This table is much more exciting when you have multiple repositories providing the same thing.